# How to setup jQuery within ESLint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, terminal, eslint

I have installed ESLint, but as you know, it cannot check jQuery syntax. So I have npm installed:

https://github.com/jquery/eslint-config-jquery/blob/master/readme.md

However, I cannot find ESLint's `.eslintrc` file in order to edit it. According to the readme file, I should be adding this code to it:

```
{
   "extends": "jquery"
}
```

How is this done?

Comment: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats

Comment: @squint, yea, I have been trying to make sense of that.  That page is packed full.

Comment: @Willow Try `CTL-F` "jquery" on the manual page

Comment: I cannot find ~/.eslintrc.  Does that mean that I have setup global ESLint wrong?

Comment: @NickZuber, when setting up with eslint --init, it does not allow jquery to be an environment.  Only browser or node as radio options.

Comment: @Willow: In the section that I linked to, just below the second heading it shows a directory structure that includes a file called `.eslintrc`. If it doesn't exist, then create it.

Comment: @squint, doesn't `eslint --init` create that file?

Comment: I have no idea, but if there's a configuration file that should be there but isn't, I'd create it.

Answer (score 8):

according to latest update of ESLint, all you have to do is to add "jQuery" to your env and set it to True.
{
    "env" : {
        "jquery": true
    },
}

Comment: Yep, my .eslintrc.json looks like this 
```{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": false,
    "jquery": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  }
}```

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot find ESLint's .eslintrc file in order to edit it.

You simply create your own `.eslintrc` in the root of your project, then you can add the following code to it:

```
{
   "extends": "jquery"
}
```

You can read more about [ESLint configuration files here](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats).

Comment: The `.eslintrc` file is created through `eslint --init` correct?

Comment: Ok, looks like the init command was creating this file.  I was able to find it.  Inside is already listed `"extends": "eslint:recommended",`. Would this then become something like, `"extends": [ "eslint:recommended", "jquery" ],` ?

Comment: @Willow Sounds right to me :) you can always double check and use [this link as a reference](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats). And yeah dotfiles are generally hidden by default, can be tricky finding them at first!

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your kind answers.  Sometimes people can get a bit condescending with silly questions like these.  Just as a note, I actually found it helpful to manually change the env to "jquery". Updating the jquery extension didn't seem to do anything, but this helped.

Comment: Do you think this actually does anything? https://github.com/jquery/eslint-config-jquery/blob/master/readme.md  Changing the env was what worked for me, but this didn't actually help.

Comment: @Willow It should extend the linting rules to add the jquery ones you've installed. If it doesn't work, you should try leaving an issue with the repository itself, but as far as I know it _should_ work